# Example Soap Body for DescribeSObjects call

Tags: ruby, soap, wsdl, salesforce

I'm running into some issues doing a describeSObject call from a ruby on rails application using Savon.  Could someone share an example of what my soap body should look like either from past experience with the salesforce partner api or general wsdl knowledge?

Here's what my application is generating:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:wsdl="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ins0="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:ins1="urn:fault.partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:ins2="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Header>
        <wsdl:SessionHeader>
            <wsdl:sessionId>REMOVED</wsdl:sessionId>
        </wsdl:SessionHeader>
    </env:Header>
    <env:Body>
        <ins0:describeSObjects>
            <wsdl:object1>Action_Plans_Settings__c</wsdl:object1>
            <wsdl:object2>QuoteLineSyncField__c</wsdl:object2>
        </ins0:describeSObjects>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I know this isn't correct, but I'm having trouble figuring out from the wsdl alone what the final soap body would look like.  I've browsed the salesforce forums and docs without much luck.

Here's the wsdl definition for this operation, perhaps some wsdl gurus can figure this out based on it:

```
<operation name="describeSObjects">
    <documentation>Describe a number sObjects</documentation>
    <input  message="tns:describeSObjectsRequest"/>
    <output message="tns:describeSObjectsResponse"/>
    <fault  message="tns:InvalidSObjectFault" name="InvalidSObjectFault"/>
    <fault  message="tns:UnexpectedErrorFault" name="UnexpectedErrorFault"/>
</operation>

<message name="describeSObjectsRequest">
    <part element="tns:describeSObjects" name="parameters"/>
</message>

<element name="describeSObjects">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element name="sObjectType" type="xsd:string" minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='100' />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</element>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:urn="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
  <soapenv:Header>
     <urn:SessionHeader>
        <urn:sessionId>someSessionId</urn:sessionId>
    </urn:SessionHeader>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
     <urn:describeSObjects>
        <urn:sObjectType>Account</urn:sObjectType>
        <urn:sObjectType>Contact</urn:sObjectType>
     </urn:describeSObjects>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```